# How detect changes in many DOM elements

Tags: angular, dom, ionic4

I code a sort of wysiwyg. I have a div container who host random tree div.

I know how to detect changes in one DOM element with MutationObserver, but I don't find how to do it with all many DOM elements.

The best way I found was using MutationObserver. The constructor need a target element, so I send it my container div. If I've receive the old and the new value, when change is detected, I can't find which element is it.

--- doc.component.html

```
<div #container contenteditable='true'>

</div>
```

--- doc.component.ts

```
... 
@ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
...
ngOnInit() {
   const target = this.container.nativeElement;
   // Set DB data in template container div
   this.dataService.getData().then(data => {
      this.renderer2.setProperty(target, 'innerHTML', data);
   });
   const config = {
     attributes: true,
     characterData: true,
     childList: true,
     subtree: true,
     attributeOldValue: true,
     characterDataOldValue: true
  };
  this.changes = new MutationObserver(
     (mutations: MutationRecord[])=> {
        mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => { 
          console.log(mutation);
        })
     };
  );
  this.changes.observe(target, config);
}
```

--- data.service.ts

```
...
jsonToHtml(json): string {
  ...
  return html;
   // expected output json: 
   { item: { id:'xxxx1', type: 'title', content: '------', sub:[]},
    item: { id:'xxxx2', type: 'paragraph', content: '------', sub:[]},
    item: { id:'xxxx3', type: 'paragraph', content: '------', sub:[]},
    item: { id:'xxxx4', type: 'paragraph', content: '------', sub:[
       item: { id:'xxxx4.1', type: 'comment', content: '------', sub:[ 
          item: { id:'xxxx4.1.1', type: 'image', content: img, sub:[]}
       ]}
    ]} }

  // expected output html :
  `<div id='xxxxx1' class='title'>
       <div class='content'>----------</div>
   </div>
   <div id='xxxxx2' class='paragraph'>
       <div class='content'>----------</div>
   </div>
   <div id='xxxxx3' class='paragraph'>
       <div class='content'>----------</div>
   </div>
   <div id='xxxxx4' class='paragraph'>
       <div class='content'>----------</div>
       <div id='xxxxx4.1' class='comment'>
            <div class='content'>----------</div>
            <div id='xxxxx4.1.1' class='image'>
                <div class='content'>---------</div>
             </div>
       </div>
   </div>`
}
getData(apiUrl): any{
  return this.apiService.get(apiUrl).then(data => {
     return this.jsonToHtml(data);
  }
}
```

Is there a better configuration, or an other way the get my goal ?
At least I need:

- new value
- item id or item path or item position

Answer (score 0):

If you use a loop through `*ngFor`, you can use the `@ViewChildren` decorator to reference all children and append some logic to them.

I have answered a question about that a while ago with the [corresponding stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzaybk?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

In the end, it works like a viewChild, you just have to iterate over every nativeElement instead of one.

Would that solve your answer ?

Comment: It could be. But in my case I have some random tree nested div.That it couldn't sort by template. I'll edit my question in this way.